# How to perform assertion for all nodes of a selector?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

In my testcafe test, I have a selector that matches multiple nodes. I want to execute an assertion on *all* nodes that are matched by this selector.

This will perform the assertion only on the first element returned by `mySelector`

```
await t.expect(mySelector.innerText).eql("foo");
```

This will perform it on all elements, but it is really verbose:

```
const count= await mySelector.count;
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    await t.expect(mySelector.nth(i).innerText).eql("foo");
}
```

Is there a built-in way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: .each function?

Comment: testcafe executes the code on the server side. There is no jQuery

Comment: I am not formiliar with testcafe. I just checked the [type definition](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/ts-defs/index.d.ts#L259) for `Selector` and it does not seem to include any form of `children` or `childNodes`. For what is exposed, the `child` function (with the filter params) might return the right selector.

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard: That's why I am using `count` and `nth`... `child` won't help either. The problem is basically with the `except` method which simply uses the first item that the selector returns.

Comment: Am I missing something? Perhaps im just unfamiliar with `testCafe`, but why are you treating DOM node selection as an aync action?

Comment: @Pytth: You *are* unfamiliar. testcafe is a node.js application, i.e. a server application. It is not executing in a browser context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't have methods like `expectEach` so I think the way you propose is the best one. It adds a few lines of code but it makes it clear what you want to check in your test.

Comment: I think `expectEach` should exist :-)

Comment: As for me, I wouldn't create complicated assertions. They can lead to complicated error messages in the report if a test fails. I'd prefer adding extra lines of code in favor of having more simple errors in the report. 
Meanwhile, feel free to add your proposal via issues in the TestCafe GitHub repository.

Comment: I see nothing complicated on combined assertion. F.e. i need to check if one of two elements exists (simple OR statement) and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Alexander Moskovkin, "TestCafe doesn't have methods like `expectEach`...". However, I decided to make `expectEach` [in my testcafe-utils module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-utils). As shown in the example usage below, I recommend interpolating `eachAsync`'s @n param in the @message param of assertions so that on test failures you know which n-th element caused the failure.

```js
const { Selector } = require('testcafe');
const tu = require('testcafe-utils');

const baseURL = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092400/ratings?ref_=tt_ov_rt';

fixture `IMDB`
  .page `${baseURL}`;

const mySelector = Selector('#main .title-ratings-sub-page table:nth-of-type(2) tr');

test('it', async t => {
  await tu.expectEach(mySelector, n => t.expect(mySelector.nth(n).innerText).match(/all/gi, `Failed on n '${n}'.`));
})
```